# Syntax Error on php echo

Tags: php

I am having trouble getting the URL to display correctly. This works now, but the link has " in front of the url. and yet the url link works fine

```
 echo "<br>" . $result['text'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;<em>(Contributed by: \"<a
 href=\"http://example.com/portfolio?ID=$result[ID]\">" .
 $result['display_name'] . "</a>" . ")</em>" . "<br>";
```

Comment: you need to escape your `"` propperly

Comment: Well... see the second part of the line and tell me what's wrong. It's clearly.

Comment: Your string ends at `uted by: "` and is not followed by anything reasonable. You probably want to put a \ in front of that ".

Comment: Actually he doesn't need that double quotes... Remove it. This snippet code is strange...

Comment: See the updated post please. It works now, but adds " to the URL. But the URL does work now. I just don't want the " in front of the URL displayed

Comment: If you don't want the " in front of the URL, remove the \" before the URL. It isn't there by some strange magic. You put it there.

Comment: Thanks all! Working now.yes, I added that \". I thought that's what the first comment was getting at that I should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sigh:

```
  echo '<br>' . $result['text'] . '&nbsp;&nbsp;<em>(Contributed by: <a
     href="http://example.come/portfolio?ID="'.$result['ID'].'">'.
     $result['display_name'] .'</a>)</em><br>';
```

Comment: ...and a dash of *ho-hum*